# C# xml Как найти узел по его значению?

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как получить доступ к узлу имея его значение?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы конкретно хотите. Что такое значение узла? Что если узлов с таким значением много? Приведите лучше пример XML и того, что нужно найти.

Comment: Зачем вам доступ у узлу, если его значение и так уже есть у вас?

Answer (score 5):

Загрузите свой XML в `XDocument` или `XElement` и воспользуйтесь методом `Descendants()` без параметров - это вернет плоскую последовательность абсолютно всех узлов исходного документа, в которой вы найдете подходящие узлы, например, с помощью `Where()`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var elements = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Value == "...").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно получить такие узлы с помощью XPath-запроса `//*[text()='значение_узла']`.

Если для работы с xml вы используете XElement/XDocument, то чтобы использовать XPath, нужно подключить пространство имен `System.Xml.XPath`. Станут доступны методы расширения `XPathSelectElement` и `XPathSelectElements`:

```
var nodes = xml.XPathSelectElements("//*[text()='значение_узла']");
```

Для старых XmlElement/XmlDocument используйте методы `SelectSingleNode` или `SelectNodes`:

```
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//*[text()='значение_узла']")
```

Comment: Когда вы используете `XElement/XDocument`, то нет вообще никакого резона использовать убогий `XPath`, когда у вас в руках есть все, чтобы работать через LINQ.

Comment: @Bulson, ну ответ имеет место быть как альтернатива. Автору вопроса подойдет один вариант, другому пользователю, нагуглившему этот вопрос - другой. Чем больше решений - тем лучше, я так думаю.